# Как вызвать функцию из другого компонента во вью?

Tags: vue.js

есть компонент block1.vue

там есть

```html
<p class="test1" @click="func()">Сontact</p>
```

есть  block2.vue
там нужно вызвать эту же функцию
но так не будет ра

```html
  <button class="test2" @click="func()">Block</button>
```

Comment: Вам не стоит так делать. Компоненты должны быть независимыми друг от друга. Вы можете воспользоваться состоянием (Vuex, Pinia), чтобы вызывать одинаковый код, управляющий логикой.

Answer (score 0):

Проще всего было бы перенести функцию из компонента в экземпляр Vue и вызывать таким образом: `$root.func()`. Но тогда компоненты становятся жёстко привязаны к экземпляру.
Поэтому мы их отвяжем через механизм событий - отправим экземпляру событие 'test':

```
<button class="test2" @click="$root.$emit('test')">Block</button>
```

a в экземпляре событие будем обрабатывать:

```
methods: {
  func: function () {
  }
},
mounted: function () {
  $on('test', $this.func);
}
```